# uniqueness of the Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

This is from Tao's "An Introduction to Measure Theory".

**Exercise 1.3.14**. Show that the Lebesgue integral $f \to \int_\mathbb{R^d}f(x)\ dx$ is the only map from the unsigned Lebesgue measurable functions $f: \mathbb R^d \to [0, +\infty]$ to $[0, +\infty]$ that obeys the following properties:

(i)(Compatibility with the simple integral): If $f$ is simple, then $\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)\ dx= \operatorname{Simp}\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)\ dx$.

(ii)(Finite additivity): $\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x) + g(x)\ dx = \int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)\ dx + \int_{\mathbb R^d}g(x)\ dx$.

(iii)(Horizontal truncation): As $n \to \infty$, $\int_{\mathbb R^d}\min(f(x), n)\ dx$ converges to $\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)\ dx$.

(iv)(Vertical truncation): As $n \to \infty$, $\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)1_{|x| \leq n}\ dx$ converges to $\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)\ dx$.

**My attempt**: Let $\alpha$ be a map satisfying the given properties. It suffices is to show that $\alpha(f) = \int_{\mathbb R^d}f$ for bounded $f$. Then by the horizontal truncation property (iii), $\alpha(\min(f,n)) = \int_{\mathbb R^d}\min(f,n) \to \alpha(f) = \int_{\mathbb R^d}f$ for any unsigned measurable $f$.

By a previous exercise, $f$ is the uniform limit of bounded simple functions $f_n$. Then $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there is an $n$ large enough s.t $\int_{\mathbb R^d}f - \operatorname{Simp}\int_{\mathbb R^d}f_n = m(A(f) - A(f_n)) \leq +\infty \cdot \epsilon \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$(ie, $n \to \infty$.), where we denote the area under the function $f$ by $A(f)$. By (i), this implies that $\alpha(f_n) \to \int_{\mathbb R^d}f$ as $n \to \infty$.

Now we show monotonicity of $\alpha$. If $0 \leq f \leq g$ are measurable, then so is $0 \leq g - f$. By (ii) we have $\alpha(g) - \alpha(f) = \alpha(g-f) \geq 0$.

Finally, assuming the simple functions $f_n$'s from above minorize $f$, we then have for large enough $n$ that $\alpha(f) - \alpha(f_n) = \alpha(f-f_n) \leq \alpha(\epsilon \cdot 1_\mathbb{R^d}) = \epsilon \cdot +\infty \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$(ie, $n \to \infty$.). Thus $\alpha(f) = \int_\mathbb{R^d}f$ for bounded $f$ and we're done.

**My question:** I was not able to use the vertical truncation property (iv) as part of the full condition of the problem. What are the issues with my solution and what should I consider instead?

Comment: Starting from the second paragraph the proof has a lot of mistakes or nonsense. For example, $\varepsilon \cdot \infty = \infty$ and doesn't even depend on $n$, so taking $n \to \infty$ doesn't do anything.

Comment: Uniform convergence allows the quantity $f - f_n$ to be bounded by $\epsilon$ on all of $\mathbb{R^d}$ by taking $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: It's true, but still $\varepsilon \cdot \infty = \infty$.

Comment: I think I somehow figured it out. For bounded $f$, and the sequence $(f_m)$ converging uniformly to $f$, we have by vertical truncation that $\operatorname{Simp}\int_{\mathbb R^d}f_m \cdot 1_{B(0,n)} \xrightarrow{m} \int_{\mathbb R^d}f \cdot 1_{B(0,n)} \xrightarrow{n} \int_{\mathbb R^d}f$ as this time the difference is bounded by $\epsilon \cdot m(B(0,n))$ instead of $\epsilon \cdot \infty$. And similarly $\alpha(f_m \cdot 1_{B(0,n)}) \xrightarrow{m} \alpha(f \cdot 1_{B(0,n)}) \xrightarrow{n} \alpha(f)$ by monotonicity. By (i), we thus have the statement holds for bounded f.

Comment: Thank you still for pointing out the flaws.